# The 'less' command-line equivalent of 'tail -f'

Tags: shell, less, tail

I would like to open up a file using less, and have it automatically scroll the file similar to `tail -f`.

I know that I can do `less file`, and then hit `Shift-F` to forward forever; like `tail -f`.

I need `less` because it provides the `--raw-control-chars` flag, which is necessary because my input is colorful.

Comment: Your explanation for the need of `less` does not make sense. `tail` passes control characters without modifications.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

use the command "F" while inside of less.

```
less mylogfile.txt
F
```

or, to do so automatically, use the +cmd option:

```
less +F mylogfile.txt
```

Comment: `less +F` does not quit when I press `q`

Comment: You have to press `CTRL`+`C` to stop watching the file, then press `q`

Answer (score 18):

I prefer `tail -F`

> -F - The -F option implies the -f option, but tail will also check to see if the file being followed has been renamed or rotated.

The `less` equivalent: `less +F --follow-name`

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a complete equivalent: **1.** it fails if the file does not exist at the time `less` is started. **2.** `less` frequently crashes when the content of the file is replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Both of those 2 options have the pro/con, for the more detail explanation, pls refer to the blog: https://www.brianstorti.com/stop-using-tail/ ; the author explained it fairly well.

Simply put:

- `tail -F *.txt` uses for reading multiple files is better than `less +F *.txt`.

In contrast, using `less +F error_log.txt` (using `Ctrl-C` & `F` to unload/load the new data) is better than `tail -F error_log.txt` for reading 1 file only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).