# Does "less" have a feature like "tail --follow=name" ("-F")

Tags: tail, less, pager

The command `less` can be used to replace `tail` in

```
tail -f file
```

to provide features like handling binary output and navigating the scrollback:

```
less +F file
```

The `+` prefix means "pretend I type that after startup", and the key `F` starts following.

But can `less` also replace

```
tail --follow=name file
```

which follows `file` even if the actual file gets deleted or moved away, like a log file that is moved to `file.log.1`, and then a new file is created with the same name as the followed file?

Comment: You could try with `less --follow-name` or `less --follow-name +F`

Comment: @don_crissti Nice... `less --follow-name +F` is it - no idea how I missed that - I was pretty sure I searched the man page for `follow`... strange. Make it an answer!

Comment: Well, some more searching reveals it's already been asked and answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74279) so I'll leave it as a comment. You can always upvote the answer there.

Comment: @don_crissti Right... except that your correct answer is not found there - `--follow-name` is described, but `+F` is never mentioned, and I think it's pretty important because it's not widely known obviously.

Comment: If you came here because of a Google search for `less follow`, READ THE QUESTION. It already answers how to make `less` follow file changes!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

#### Yes, `less` can follow by file name

The feature has a fairly obscure syntax:

```
less --follow-name +F file.log
```

With less, `--follow-name` is different from the `tail` option `--follow=name`.
It does not make `less` follow the file, instead it **modifies the behaviour** of the command key <kbd>F</kbd> inside of less to follow based on the file name, not the file descriptor.

Also, there is no normal option to start `less` in follow mode.
But you can use the command line to give **keystrokes to execute** after startup, by prefixing them with `+`.
Combining the modifier option with `+F`, `less` will actually start in the (modified) follow mode.

Use `+F` alone for the equivalent of plain `tail -f`:

```
less +F file.log
```

Comment: I suspect that if you follow an infinite stream with less, this will eventually exhaust your memory because unlike tail -f, the amount of memory used is not limited by the terminal scrollback limit (unless the terminal scrollback limit is also infinite). less +F has to preserve the entire scrollback history, and cannot rely on reloading slices from a file on the harddisk.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Interesting point. `less` has options to control the buffer size used per file (`-b` and `-B`), it's not obvious to me whether the size is limited by default.

Comment: The man page for `-B` says that "By default, when data is read from a pipe, buffers are allocated automatically as needed. If a large amount of data is read from the pipe, this can cause a large amount of memory to be allocated. The -B option disables this automatic allocation of buffers for pipes, so that only 64 K ( or the amount of space specified by the -b option) is used for the pipe.". So that means when reading from a infinite pipe, infinite memory is allocated by default, but if reading from a file like a log file, then 64 K slices is used by default.

Comment: My favorite `less` command to follow a growing rotating log file is this: `less -N --follow-name +F ~/cpu_log.log`. The `-N` also adds line numbers. I've now cited your answer and [added `--follow-name` to my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139866/how-do-i-cat-and-follow-a-file/687072#687072).

Comment: So pressing `F` makes less refresh the file?

Comment: @HappyFace that depends on what you mean with refresh, exactly. Read new data that was added to the file: Yes. But not if you mean reload the whole file or part of it, discarding what you currently have.

Answer (score 8):

Also you can activate the follow mode if you call `less filename` like normal and then press `Shift + F`. With `Ctrl + C` you can then deactivate follow mode again.

But be aware that by default this will not work in an alpine docker image.

Answer (score 7):

In Fedora at least less has a +F option that follows the contents of a file just like tail -f does..

Update, try hitting F in less to toggle to follow mode as well

Comment: Are you sure? My less has a conflicting option named the same, `-F`: The man page of less says: `-F or --quit-if-one-screen`. Which version of `less` do you have? Mine says  `less 458` with the option `-V`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467/the-less-command-line-equivalent-of-tail-f

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the link! That seems not to be a gnu less. The full first line of `less -V` is `less 458 (GNU regular expressions)`. Please give me your version.

Comment: Yes I am sure, but go ahead and down vote me, stackexchange needs to share the love

Comment: (mingw) less 481 (PCRE regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2015  Mark Nudelman
(fedora) less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2016  Mark Nudelman

Comment: Just to be sure you did think I down voted you: No, I upvoted you.

Comment: And do not take the votes so seriously. Your posts are actually really valuable to me. I know there were lots of conflicts between the unix from HP, `HPUX`, Simens had one, Sun had two... but now, I did not expect there are still conflicts.